# SXA Search Build Query for Multiple Templates

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I am new to SXA & using SXA tags feature for getting related items. I have two or more templates from where I want to get the data based on SXA tags conditions. When I am using individual template then I get the correct result but on combining two templates, result is incorrect.

**Query:**  *+sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags;+custom:language_1|en;+sxa:ExcludeCurrentPage;sort:smallcreateddate_2[desc];template:{c5c069ce-b404-4d44-83f3-45ac2afbe80b};template:{342696b0-2b67-406f-8e49-c7acc7894741}*

More precisely, I want to use condition for templates like

*(Template1 or Template2) AND +sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags;+custom:language_1|en;+sxa:ExcludeCurrentPage;sort:smallcreateddate_2[desc];*

[image]

Can anyone help me to write correct query?
Thanks